# Can I compile views in my Rails application to a .class file with JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, warbler

I know that you can easily compile all controllers and models using `jrubyc`, but how can I compile the views (like HAML or ERB)? I am open to solutions that use `jrubyc` or `warbler`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the compiled view?

Comment: I'm not sure if this sounds right, I have the whole project compiled but the view,and I don't want the customer to be able to mess with the views like basic text files.

Comment: Maybe, just obfuscate them ?

Comment: @Khaledvic are you concerned about having a customer be able to edit the view? If so, then just (when releasing) make the views read-only

Comment: yeah I was hoping for a more "jrubyc" like solution,I read a lot about the mechanism that jrubyc uses to compile,it stores chunks of memory of the compiled code to the file, so I think it should be easy to do the same with the views or even the configuration files